# Who is funding Avengers facilities?

Tags: marvel-cinematic-universe, marvel, avengers-age-of-ultron

In *Avengers: Age of Ultron*, we learned that

> Avengers works like an organization separate from S.H.I.E.L.D. Avengers was also working together with NATO. Does that mean the government is funding Avengers?

Or,

> Is this just Tony Stark? Having *Stark Tower* renamed as *Avengers Tower* indicates this, but after seeing all those things I doubt even a billionaire could support that.

Comment: NATO? When were they mentioned?

Comment: @PaulD.Waite In the very beginning of the movie.

Comment: @PaulD.Waite The Avengers handed the captive from the start of the film to NATO.

Comment: @Keen: ah! Gotcha.

Comment: So what are the expenditure of the Avengers.

Answer (score 29):

When Hill meets the Avengers when they return to Avengers Tower early in the movie, she calls Tony *"boss"*. He replies:

> **Tony Stark:** [pointing to Steve] Uh, actually, he's the boss. I just pay for everything, and design everything and make everyone look cooler.

I have no memory of other fundings; maybe NATO or some governments may be part of funding the Avengers.

As pointed out by [@KutuluMike](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/users/2816/kutulumike?tab=profile) in the comments we learn in *Ant-Man* that

> the new Avengers building is an unused Stark Industries facility, strengthening the idea that the Avengers are funded by Tony Stark, personally or through Stark Industries.

Comment: Of interest: the "new" Avengers facility is apparently a formerly-unused Stark warehouse, giving even more credence to the idea that Stark's funding it all.

Answer (score 10):

Based on what is said in the movie it is save to assume that Tony Stark funds the Avengers himself.

It is however important to note there is no way to equate a comic book universe economy with the real world economy.

The amount of money characters like Tony Stark or Bruce Wayne spend to do the things they do would probably bankrupt the wealthiest real world billionaires.

Comment: Can't be true because the Avengers Initiative invited Stark to join; it therefore already existed.

Comment: @Gaius: That was before SHIELD was disbanded though, Stark could have picked it up afterwards.

Comment: @Gaius The Avengers Initiative and the Avengers are two different things. The Initiative was Fury's plan to create a team, but that plan was shelved by the counsel. Fury got the team together anyway but then they became their own thing with no direct SHIELD oversight. Watch the last 5 minutes of Avengers.

Comment: Stark invented a cold fusion energy source. I doubt money is much of an issue to him, or is the cost really really up there, as the biggest cost in any equipment is the power source/Fuel.

Answer (score 1):

In the previous Iron Man films in Iron Man 2 Tony did hand over the position of CEO to pepper so pepper runs stark industries however he still is the majority shareholder and owns the company and therefore gains a percentage of the profits through dividends from the company. Also during the film he does state that Pepper is busy running the worlds biggest technology conglomerate and therefore shows that the company is one of the biggest in the world and therefore the Avengers most likely are funded by Tony but technically from Stark Industries mainly because Hill is an employee for the Avengers is you remember from the previous Captain America 2 film. 
Therefore the avengers have the funding of the biggest tech company in the world and therefore through he profits of the company have access to plenty of funding and the latest technology advancements along with the help of Tony all because he owns the company Pepper is running for him.

http://marvelcinematicuniverse.wikia.com/wiki/Stark_Industries

Also if you check the wiki Stark Industries now also provides privatized security as part of its services which are the Avengers meaning the avengers are funded by Stark Industries and in other words as I said Tony who owns it, this is how they have so much they have the backing of a company who is the worlds biggest tech conglomerate and Pepper management skills for finance, and since globalizing private security most likely some government funding to Stark Industries to pay for it's services so the company had more income to invest in funding the avengers as it is a business.