# How do the Avengers communicate?

Tags: marvel, marvel-cinematic-universe, avengers, avengers-age-of-ultron

In the Age of Ultron, the individual Avengers talk to each other over long distances.  Like Captain America is in Sokovia and he just starts talking to Tony Stark who is in New York, expecting to get an answer.  But they do not have any visible ear pieces or microphones.  Also, there would likely be a security breach if they had visible blue tooth devices that could be stolen.

**So how do the Avengers talk to each other over long distances?**  Do they have some microscopic microphones?  How does the sound get in their ears when they receive a message from others?  Think Captain America or Romanov who do not have fancy Iron Man suits that could have built in audio systems.  Also, think how Ultron can tap into any phone signal, so the Avengers cannot use normal phone channels unless they have some added encryption.

Comment: http://content.time.com/time/specials/packages/article/0,28804,1934259_1934277_1934497,00.html

Comment: [Avengers Membership/Communicator Card](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=xlkjdBBYyRg)

Comment: Poorly, look at all of the trouble they could have stopped if they sit and talk properly!

Answer (score 12, accepted):

In Iron Man 3, during the house party fight at the end of the film, you can't (easily) see an earpiece in Tony's ear. But it gets knocked out at some point during the fight, and this means that he can no longer communicate with Jarvis.

It's a teensy little blue glowy earbud that looks like it just sits inside your ear, and is apparently responsible for both transmitting and receiving (given that Jarvis can't hear Tony).

Since Stark is apparently the Avenger's outfitter/[financier](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/a/87324/38386)/housing office, it's pretty reasonable to assume that they all got a sweet earpiece each.

[image: Earpiece in iron man 3]

Here's a picture of it on the ground in Iron Man 3. It fell out of his left ear (I believe), or at least that's the ear he puts it back in. I decided against combing through the film(s) to look for a direct shot down both of his ears, and I'll gladly concede the accept to anyone that does.

Comment: There is a scene in AOU where Quicksilver can be seen putting one in his ear. Is just after he selects a pair of running shoes in one of the closets in Avengers tower.

Comment: @CodeMed "Really fancy" is kinda Tony Stark's thing

Comment: @CodeMed it's not that hard to hear a voice through the inside of the head. Ears and mouth are directly connected, aren't they? That's why when you yawn your ears can get unstuck.

Comment: The ear piece is how they connect into a network. But the OP asks how signals avoid eavesdropping from Ultron as they pass through a network. Your answer fails to address most of the OP.

Answer (score 10):

SHIELD has developed inner-ear communication devices that don't require an external piece, as seen in the first episode of Agents of Shield:

> Ward: Coulson said I'd need my comm receiver encoded.
>   Don't know if you've worked with that model before.
>   It's *Fitz smashes it with a hammer* Brand-new.
>
> Simmons: He'll repurpose the I.D.I.S. Chip. Don't need the external receiver for the inner-ear comms anymore.
>
> Ward: So, how does it...
>
> Simmons: Embedded sensorineural silicone matched to your DNA. It's very posh.

You can see below, Fitz smashing Ward's comm receiver to get the chip out.

[image: Fitz smashing Ward's communicator]