# In The Avengers (2012), How did they communicate at the climax without any ear device even though the inner ear technology was created in 2013?

Tags: marvel-cinematic-universe, marvel, avengers, the-avengers-2012

***Note: This is not a duplicate of [How do the Avengers Communicate?](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/92106/how-do-the-avengers-communicate)*** The question in the link is about Avengers:Age Of Ultron (2015) but this question is about The Avengers (2012)

---

In the Avengers (2012), in the climax fight how did the Avengers communicate with each other without any sort of ear equipment?

The inner ear piece communication technology seen in Avengers 2 was developed by SHIELD and introduced in Agents Of Shield *S01E01* in **2013**. Also Tony Stark created the little blue glowing earbud in Iron Man 3 (**2013**).

So how did the Avengers communicate without any ear equipment in the Battle of New York?

Iron Man can be neglected from the list because his suite has a built-in phone, but how did Captain America, Black Widow and Hawkeye communicate?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do the Avengers communicate?](http://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/92106/how-do-the-avengers-communicate)

Comment: @Petersaber In Agents Of Shield S01E01 Ward brings his Ear device and calls it a brand new when Finn breaks it and replaces with Inner ear model. This suggests that Inner ear model were designed by SHIELD in 2013 and not before. They were introduced in 2013!

Comment: I understand and get your argument that they're not dupes, as the other question and answers all specifically deal with later movies, but there's very little, if any, reason to not assume that the tech wasn't used but not mentioned just a year or so before. If you want to get your question re-opened/de-duped, you'll need to **edit** your question (not open a new one, and not use just the comments) and explain *why* you think that the tech didn't exist or wasn't used. Otherwise, the answers *will* be the same, defining them as dupes.

Comment: Why do you think earpieces didn't exist in 2012?  

[Headsets](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Headset_(audio)), which combine headphones with microphones, were invented in 1910.  [Bluetooth](http://www.bluetooth.com/Pages/History-of-Bluetooth.aspx) technology existed by 1998.

Plenty of versions would have been commercially available in 2012, let alone anything Stark or SHIELD could have invented.

Comment: @Nerrolken I don't think earpieces with encrypted transmission and which work even under high pressure and temperature are there?

Comment: @AdityaBlaze  Why not?  Sure, encryption probably wouldn't be available at RadioShack, but the Secret Service have been using wireless earpieces for sensitive operations for decades.  Do you really think Nick Fury couldn't get his hands on a few?

Comment: @Nerrolken I should accept the fact that Nick Fury has got hands on them as the answer suggests your comment. :)

Comment: "I don't think earpieces with encrypted transmission and which work even under high pressure and temperature are there?" there's also no super soldier serums, helicarriers, iron man suits, or a lot of other things we see in the MCU. just because *we* don't have it, it doesn't mean *they* don't have it.

Comment: "this suggests that Inner ear model were designed by SHIELD in 2013 and not before" — or it suggests that after a triumphant test run by the Avengers, they were widely deployed throughout SHIELD in 2013.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

**They have ear pieces.**

When Black Widow says “I can do it, I can shut the portal down” the camera switches to Steve Rogers on the ground. He lowers his head and reaches his arm towards his ear. Just like you might do if you were using an ear piece in a war zone.

[image]

> Do it! - *Just after Captain America sold out to Nike*

Other scenes with the hand to ear movement (courtesy of [@Passerby](http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/23230317#23230317))

> Capt does the hand to ear thing when the Helicarrier is first attacked, and Him and IM are trying to reboot the engine. BW does it after she hides from the hulk, and Fury broadcasts that Barton is involved. She says "this is black widow, im on it"

[image]

> This is Agent Romanov, I copy - *Romanov admits to being a glorified receptionist*

[image]

> Speak English - *or apparently, French*

There is also a image of the ear piece while Iron Man asked Captain America to look at some power relays before the battle at NYC

https://goo.gl/photos/HkxdLVSc5eb3GNZe7

Comment: Couldn't figure out why you were quoting the now infamous Shia LaBeouf video at the bottom of your answer at first. I am ashamed of myself.

Comment: You may want to edit to provide a link, while not immediate [goo.gl is going away](https://goo.gl/).

Comment: You should change or remove the goo.gl link, since it is now dead.