# Has the Avengers' comm system ever been hacked?

Tags: marvel, marvel-cinematic-universe, avengers

Here is a screen shot of Tony Stark's ear piece on the ground during Iron Man 3 after it had been knocked out of his head in a fight:

[image].

Tony was not able to communicate with JARVIS without the earpiece.

**Has anyone ever stolen one of the ear pieces and used it to get into the Avengers' comm system?**

Comment: @DownVoter, Ultron hacked the entire internet and also stole Tony's drones. Stealing or hacking an earpiece is a plausible plot line.

Comment: A better question is In Civil War, how was Captain America's team communicating?

Comment: @Derek Do you mean like [this other question](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/92106/how-do-the-avengers-communicate)? Or do you mean something else?

Comment: I mean because they were on opposite sides, and would not really want the other side to hear their own team's conversations. If they're on the same Stark-owned system...just sayin

Comment: Stark himself hacked the comms of the Quinjet Natasha Romanoff was pilotting in Stuttgart (to play awesome music to announce his arrival) when they went to intercept Loki in Stuttgart in The Avengers/Avengers Assemble.

Comment: @Derek: It's fair to assume that the comm system has channels, as it's nothing more than a fancy walkie talkie system. Cap could have picked a different channel. But if Tony then sets his channel to Cap's channel, that means that Cap can hear Tony too! Either party is incentivized to not listen in on the other party as it means they are either incapable of communicating to their own party, or they are broadcasting themselves too.